# Flutter-Button with icon onselected

Tags: flutter, dart, button, radio-button, icons

[image]

I am new to flutter.  I use group button to build such a screen, what kind of widget can i use? I need it to appear when the button is selected and disappear when it is not selected.

I tried to do it with a group button but can’t add an icon there, i also tried to do it using the chip widget, but there the close icon only works on clicking on it.

Comment: check the answer and tell me if it work for you

Comment: I need a close icon to appear when the button is selected and a close icon to appear when the button is not selected.  I don't want the button to disappear when I click on the close icon, I want the icon to disappear when I click on the button

Comment: your statement is not clear to me can you explain it

Answer (score 1):

you can use InputChip widget like this

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ChipApp());

class ChipApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xff6750a4), useMaterial3: true),
      home: const InputChipExample(),
    );
  }
}

class InputChipExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputChipExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<InputChipExample> createState() => _InputChipExampleState();
}

class _InputChipExampleState extends State<InputChipExample> {
  int inputs = 3;
  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('InputChip Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              spacing: 5.0,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                inputs,
                (int index) {
                  return InputChip(
                    label: Text('Person ${index + 1}'),
                    selected: selectedIndex == index,
                    onSelected: (bool selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (selectedIndex == index) {
                          selectedIndex = null;
                        } else {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    onDeleted: () {
                      setState(() {
                        inputs = inputs - 1;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  inputs = 3;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Reset'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

check the details in the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputChip-class.html)